# Add a barcode mulitple times based on the class before

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode

I have a list of numbers and I need to automatically have them each turned into a barcode.  I can get the first one to change, but I cannot get the ones after to change.  I have a jquery barcode generator.  I am pretty new to this.  Please help.

```
<table width=180 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
  <tr> 
    <td class="barcode_needed">10133</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td class="barcode_needed">20133</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td class="barcode_needed">30133</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://barcode-coder.com/css/style.css?ft=1298939919" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-barcode-last.min.js"></script>


<script>
  $("td.barcode_needed").after("<div id='bcTarget1'>");
  $("#bcTarget1").barcode(('G' + $("td.barcode_needed").html()), "code128");
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating multiple `<div>` elements with the same `id` attribute. When you do this:

```
$("#bcTarget1")
```

jQuery will only find the first one and so you only get one barcode. You're also mixing up your elements by inserting a `<div>` as a child of a `<tr>`.

First, fix your HTML structure (including the duplicate `id` attributes):

```
$('td.barcode_needed').append('<div class="bcTarget">');
```

This puts your `<div>` inside the `<td>` (so that your element nesting is correct) and replaces the `id` attribute with a `class`.

Then, fix the barcodes by referencing the next structure.

```
$('.bcTarget').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.barcode(
        'G' + $this.closest('td.barcode_needed').text(),
        'code128'
    );
});
```

The [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) call goes up the tree to find the closest ancestor that matches the selector. You can just use [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) on the table cells that you find as the `<div>`s you just added will still be empty when you call `.text`.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eaYTZ/

You'll probably want to play with the styling a bit of course.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you.  This code is running multiple times as I have to attach it to each of my orders.  I print my orders in batches so the jquery appears more then once.  Is there a way I can have the jquery only run on the final time it appears on the page.  I wish I could just have it write in only once, but that is impossible in this instance.

Comment: @user764728: I think adding just one `$(document).ready(...)` call per page would be the easiest thing. You could set a global "I've already added the barcodes" flag and make the `each` callback do nothing if the flag is set, then set the flag to true after each `.each`; that's a bit of a hack but it'll do the job with minimal work.

Comment: @user764728: A better quick hack would be to check if `$this` has any children, if does then do nothing, if it doesn't then do the `$this.barcode(...)` stuff.